# How can I open a file from a shared location on OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, windows

I'm fairly new to OSX, and I'm trying to do some work stuff here.
On my job, we usually have to open some files that are located on a shared network folder, so for example, I would hit WindowsKey + R, which brings up the Run command window, and then enter something like:

file://server/clients/T\TestClient\XXXX\XXXX\Email.eml

That just opens the email directly.
I usually have to access network locations as well to browse for files.

How can I do this on OSX?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it
In case someone runs into the same question

From Finder, command + k brings up the window to connect to a remote machine

I entered the smb:// and the path I wanted to, it prompted for credentials and that was it